# Magento 1.* rest API php oauth authentication

Tags: rest, api, magento-1.9

Having an issue with my Magento 1.9 rest API,
Everythings is configurated on the magento (oauth user /keys permissions)

I used the Magento documention to get the product list and connect to oauth:

Here is the code:

```
// $callbackUrl is a path to your file with OAuth authentication example for the Admin user
$callbackUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8880/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8880/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
// var_dump($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);die();
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8880/admin/oAuth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8880/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'bbc9709fae90569357a40717f75ce911';
$consumerSecret = 'd5c43ea001aa8937c78c25b6c6aa530e';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_PLAINTEXT, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);

        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($productsList);
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    echo "&lt;br/&gt;";
    print_r($e->lastResponse);
}
```

When calling this code i get a xhr call :

http://127.0.0.1:8880/admin/oAuth_authorize?oauth_token=e8e8e6d8fd36bf55361231f3910e5ee5

My app is returning [XHR] Fatal Error.
But when i call the url on the browser:
[image]

I get this, clicking authorize, just shutdown my local server(everytimes):
[image]

I'm really stuck on this point....tried everything I know, if someone have an idea, you'r welcome.

Comment: Is possible use REST API without OAuth? @ user3013440

Comment: Rest Api un general yes, but Magento 1.9 rest Api nope ... or i didn't found the way :S

Comment: Invalid auth/bad request (got a 401, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
oauth_problem=token_rejected  How can  isolve the above error? @Ggs my code : https://codeshare.io/2Wj4QM

Comment: You 'r trying to call the magento rest API?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to use REST API?